# Touch Events not captured by webview Android Samsung Galaxy Note

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I need to display some sort of data in an html page by a webview. I am getting a blank screen and on clicking that black screen all the data is getting displayed. I captured a screen shot of the log cat which shows "no_fast_draw = false". Does anybody have the same issue?

[image]

Comment: can you post the implementation ?or more details as how you are calling it ?

Comment: I am sorry i cannot post the implementation. But the implementation is working on all other devices like. Samsung Galaxy GT-P1000, motorola atrix, google nexus.

Comment: Have you found solution for that?